# UITableview change padding dynamically

Tags: ios, uitableview

we have an iphone app and are developing it now as universal app. We want to use the same views including tableviews. On the left handside, we are using a tableview for navigation which can be expanded dynamically and on the right handside, we have our viewControllers which are basically the same like for iPhone.

Because of design and UX we do not want to stretch them to fill the whole view on the right side, we want to them to be centered with padding on left and right side. This padding should be dynamically, because if the menu on left side is expanded, the padding should be reduced.

We tried to achieve by overwriting the setframe method of the cells, but its a bit awkward, tried someone of you before something like that?

tia

Comment: Making the app available on the iPad, but adding padding instead of utilizing the extra space a poor design in most cases. That aside, are you using auto layout or not? (since it would effect my answer)

Comment: In that point we are dependent on the customer :/ .. no we can't because we have to support iOS 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the top level `UIView` of my `UIViewController` I'd create a padding view.
Have it go the full width of the `superview`, grow/shrink as needed and pin it to the left and right sides.

Inside the padding view, create your content view. Make the view however wide you want it to be, don't have it re-size horizontally and don't pin it to the left or right sides. Stick it in the center of your padding view.

Now if you say... shift the padding view to the right and shrink it by changing the origin.x and the size.width on the frame, the inner content view will remain fixed sized and centered in the padding view. This would also you to slide in a menu on either the left or right side of the screen.

**Edit Based on Comment:**
If your internal content view is table, but you want scroll bar on the far right.

Change the `frame.size.height` of your inner content view(`UITableView` to match you table view's `contentSize.height` value. This will make the table as big as the content. Turn off vertical scrolling. (Note: you'll have to update the height of your table view any time you modify the height of the contents.)

Instead of having your padding a simple `UIView`, make it a `UIScrollView`.

Now your table view is a static height and doesn't scroll, no scroll bar. The padding view now controls scrolling which means you can scroll by touching the padding as well as having the scroll bar on the right hand edge of the padding view.

Comment: Good approach but in this case, the scrollbar would be pinned next to the tableView if centered and menu on the left is not expanded. Our goal would be that the scrollbar always stays on the right side on same place.